# getting the error Unsupported major.minor version 51.0 (unable to load class org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer) after using java7

Tags: java, jersey, version, java-7

I was getting the error:

> Unsupported major.minor version 51.0 (unable to load class org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer)

while moving my code to test server.

So I recompiled my code to java 7 and put it again in the test server but it shows the same error.

I am using Jersey version 2.13

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is the problem with your code. Looks like the problem is with server itself. 
As the error itself says that (unable to load class org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer) implies that your glassfish version is not compatible with JRE you've installed.

Please have this checked.

Comment: The code is working fine with the same jersey lib and JRE in eclipse but when I am trying to deploy the code (making a .war file) in test server it is showing the error Unsupported major.minor version 51.0 (unable to load class org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer)

Comment: That's what I'm trying to say, you need to check whether those libraries are added in your test server.
It seems nothing but a compatibility issue.

Comment: yes ...All the lib have been added in the test server too

Comment: does the test server run without any error if the application is not deployed ...?

Comment: Yes the test server is running without any error ...Still not able to resolve the issue

Comment: Then compile your code with same java version that your server is running on. 
I've already told you it's just a compatibility issue.

Comment: I'm already using the the same java version compiled code as running on my test server